# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ClientDetails' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I get this exception thrown whenever I try and submit data through a form to this database :-

- Exception

  **Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ClientDetails' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

However, the form doesn't have a field so data can enter the identity column (PK) so I'm at a loss as to why this is occuring.

At the moment I'm using the standard asp.net mvc submit button but I will link it eventually to a jquery dialog button

The ClientNo Column which is the said column the exception is referring to has the following attributes

- Name - ClientNo
- type - int
- NULLS - NO
- Identity Spec - Yes
- Is Identity - Yes
- Increment - 1
- Seed - 1

The ClientNo has data  900 onwards etc

This exception is also thrown when the client form has no data entered in form

Its thrown on a DataCOntext.SubmitChanges() method

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create1(ClientDetail client)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
            client = new ClientDetail();



                UpdateModel(client);
                //Debug Code
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AddNewClient Create1");
                repo.AddNewClient(client);
                //Debug Code
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Save Create1");


                // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException thrown at this line  
                repo.Save();

                //Debug Code - never reached
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saved Changes");


              //  return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = client.ClientNo });




            }
            return View(client);
        }

public void AddNewClient(ClientDetail client)
       {    
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start Insert On Submit");

            db.ClientDetails.InsertOnSubmit(client);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finish Insert On Submit");
       }

public void Save()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In Save Method");
            db.GetChangeSet();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got ChangeSet"); 
            db.SubmitChanges();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exit Save Method");
        }
Is this the query everyone is talking about

[Column(Storage="_ClientNo", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public int ClientNo
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ClientNo;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ClientNo != value))
                {
                    this.OnClientNoChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._ClientNo = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("ClientNo");
                    this.OnClientNoChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know a solution or reason as to why this is occuring?

Thank you

Comment: How do you "submit" data to the database ?

Comment: This error is generated when you want to add value to the seed column and when identity_insert is off. So how you saving your data to the database?

Comment: it would be good if you could post the query.

Comment: @Abdul Muq - using SubmitChanges methods from linq to Sql class

Comment: I can't seem to work the code block correctly but the query in Linq-Sql is

Comment: [Column(Storage="_ClientNo", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
  public int ClientNo
  {
   get
   {
    return this._ClientNo;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._ClientNo != value))
    {
     this.OnClientNoChanging(value);
     this.SendPropertyChanging();
     this._ClientNo = value;
     this.SendPropertyChanged("ClientNo");
     this.OnClientNoChanged();
    }
   }
  }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add IsDbGenerated=true To ClientNo Property

```
[Column(Storage="_ClientNo", DbType="Int NOT NULL", **IsDbGenerated=true,** IsPrimaryKey=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)] 
public int ClientNo
```

Comment: +1 for knowing the answer before the code was formatted properly

Comment: this answer doesnt work anymore! why? im getting this error:
 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ColumnAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'IsPrimaryKey'

Comment: @Tman Make sure you are using System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute, not System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ColumnAttribute

Comment: It says that "System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute is a type and not a namespace"

Comment: @Tman you have bunch of nonono s in your code. You incorrectly add using statement. Also, you should not change auto generated files manually. It's better to read some documentation about entity framework and linq2sql first. You should be using partial class to apply that attribute I guess

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supply values to be inserted into an Identity column as part of an insert. They are automatically generated as an atomic part of the `INSERT` operation. This can be temporaily disabled on a per table basis with the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command.

Either, you should alter the database shcema but I do not reccomend this or better, you should not supply a value, or supply a `NULL` value for the `Client_NO` column in your insert.

In SQL you can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to get the auto genrated value. the model will be automatically updated with this value.

Use [archil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639343/archil)'s answer to tell the model not pass the this column in the generated select.

```
[Column(Storage="_ClientNo",
    DbType="Int NOT NULL", 
    IsDbGenerated=true,
    IsPrimaryKey=true, 
    UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]  
public int ClientNo
```

Note the edition of IsDBGenerated to the arrtributes.