# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Person' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, mysql

I've the following code:

**viewmodel**

```
 public class UserVM
 {
public int PersonID { get; set; }        
public string FirstName { get; set; }       
public string LastName { get; set; }      
public string UserName { get; set; }       
public string Password1 { get; set; }     
}
```

**Password model**

```
public partial class Password
{       
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }       
    public string Password1 { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

**Person model**

```
   public partial class Person1
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonID { get; set;     
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserAuthRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
  // POST: api/Person1
    [ResponseType(typeof(Person1))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostPerson1(UserVM vm)
    {
        var pers = new Person1
        {
            Title = vm.Title,
            FirstName = vm.FirstName,
            LastName = vm.LastName,
            UserName = vm.UserName,               
        };
        var word = new Password();
        using (var context = new VybeEstoreEntities1())
        {
           context.People1.Add(pers);
            word.PersonID = pers.PersonID;                            
            word.Password1 = vm.Password1;               
            context.Passwords.Add(word);
            context.SaveChanges();
         }
```

I'm getting this error:

{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Person' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

The Password object has a 0 for the PersonId property when I call password.Add. The database tables are Person and Password. PersonId is the PK of Person and is an auto-increment identity. PersonId is the FK on password.

I get that error when I'm trying to save new person and save the personId to password table.

**Updated**

PASSWORD TABLE

[image]

PERSON TABLE

[image]

Comment: Add IsDbGenerated = True to PersonID. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016306/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-clientdetails-when-i?rq=1

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar i get this error Error 3 Named attribute argument expected C:\Users\netvybez\Desktop\calling 24\150204 (8h 33) - Call24-xman\Call24\Models\Person1.cs 19 61 Call24

Comment: and tried to use the name space those guys were arguing about but i'm not winning

Comment: can you do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541338/identity-insert-is-set-to-off-visual-studio

Comment: @Arie thanx it help me a lot i'm no longer having that error  but problem now is that when i'm save is saving zero on password table(personid) instead of saving the number that is  auto generated on the personid on person table.

Comment: Is "AUTO_INCREMENT" set up correctly inyour table in DB? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: auto increment is correct and it does increment correctly on person table but when i want to take that same number to password table saves zero not the correct number i ll show you screen shots shortly

Comment: @Arie Please check updated pictures

Comment: the problem seems to be this: word.PersonID = pers.PersonID; <- at this point your 'person' data wasn't yet saved to the database, so the ID is not yet set (equals 0). you have to SaveChanges() before doing that. also, is it fine if there is no foreign key on your password table connecting it to your Person table (I mean, it accepts 0 as personID)?

Comment: mmmmmh seems interesting now. So how can i achieve this then ? yes, there is foreign key on the password table but i didnt set as foreign key.

Comment: @Arie i tried to set personId as  foreign key on password table. Yes it did save the correct value but i don't want to set personId as  foreign key. i want to save the value  without setting personId as  foreign key.  how can i achieve that?

Comment: @Arie thanx for giving me the clue